# How to pass a string value ' String_value ' if i cant use " " and ' '?

Tags: javascript, php

Actually here i am passing a int value and string value by      **javascript:function();** ,
  im little bit confuse how to send string value by using single quote ' ' because here echo is using double " " and href is using single ' ' .

```
echo "<td align='center'><a href='javascript:EditNotePopup($id,$ref_id,$string_value);'><i class=' icon-edit'></i></a></td>";
```

so,above i cannot use ' ".$srting_value." ' or \ symbol . How can i fix it and pass a string value using '   '

For Example,i am trying like this

```
       javascript:EditPopup(1,09898,'hello_world');
```

so hello world is using '   '.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Inline events are bad practice. Using `addEventListener` you wouldn't have any of these issues.

Comment: Another way would be to escape the string value, look for htmlspecialchars() in php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape with a backslash

```
echo '<td align="center"><a href="javascript:EditNotePopup('.$id.','.$ref_id.',\''.$string_value.'\');"><i class=" icon-edit"></i></a></td>';
```

Comment: @sheriff, sorry, my answer had a syntax error. Try my updated answer